# Override env values defined in container spec

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, environment-variables, containers, configmap

I have a configmap where I have defined the following key-value mapping in the `data` section:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: test-config
data:
  TEST: "CONFIGMAP_VALUE"
```

then in the definition of my container (in the deployment / statefulset manifest) I have the following:

```
        env:
        - name: TEST
          value: "ANOTHER_VALUE"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: test-config
```

When doing this I was expecting that the value from the configmap (TEST="CONFIGMAP_VALUE") will override the (default) value specified in the container spec (TEST="ANOTHER_VALUE"), but this is not the case (TEST always gets the value from the container spec). I couldn't find any relevant documentation about this - is it possible to achieve such env variable value overriding?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#container-v1-core):

> `envFrom` : List of sources to populate environment variables in the container. The keys defined within a source must be a C_IDENTIFIER. All invalid keys will be reported as an event when the container is starting. When a key exists in multiple sources, the value associated with the last source will take precedence. Values defined by an Env with a duplicate key will take precedence. Cannot be updated.

So above clearly states the **env** will take precedence than **envFrom**.

> When a key exists in multiple sources, the value associated with the last source will take precedence.

So, for overriding, don't use `envFrom`, but define the value twice within `env`, see below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: test-config
data:
  TEST: "CONFIGMAP_VALUE"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busy
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    env:
    - name: TEST
      value: "DEFAULT_VAULT"
    - name: TEST
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: test-config
          key: TEST
    command:
    - "sh"
    - "-c"
    - >
      while true; do
        echo "$(TEST)";
        sleep 3600;
      done
```

Check:

```
kubectl logs busy -n default
CONFIGMAP_VALUE
```

Comment: what if I have a entrypoint.sh in Docker image which also have a same environment variable which is generated by export TEST=123456?

Comment: @focuszheng Then that will take precedence, since it's the last thing to run.

Comment: the link above is broken. Not sure if this answer is still accurate / valid. In my case, both environment variables are added with both having different values!