# kubernetes: precedence of environmental variables

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, configmap

Assuming a pod has an environmental variable set both in its spec, as e.g. below

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: env-print-demo
    image: bash
    env:
    - name: FOO
      value: "BAR"
```

as also injected to it via a `ConfigMap` (but with a different value) which is the one that will be taken into account?

Answer (score 3):

When a key exists in multiple sources, **the value associated with the last source will take precedence**.

[Override env values defined in container spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398272/override-env-values-defined-in-container-spec)

Answer (score -1):

the value that will be taken is the config map because config map will override the env value that have the same key

Comment: The [spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#container-v1-core) states that values set using `env` will take precedence over the configMap in `envFrom`. _When a key exists in multiple sources, the value associated with the last source will take precedence. Values defined by an Env with a duplicate key will take precedence._