# Kubernetes yaml file - Same property in env and envFrom

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubeconfig yaml file which contains the property "ENABLED" in env. There is a secrets file being read using envFrom as well which also contains the property "ENABLED". Which one will get picked up at runtime?

```
env:
   - name: ENABLED
     value: "true"                
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
    name: test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [kubernetes documentation of `envFrom`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#container-v1-core) states that:

> ... Values defined by an Env with a duplicate key will take precedence. ...

Thus, the value defined by `env` will take precedence.

The answer was take from [nightfury1204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6878708/nightfury1204)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398272/override-env-values-defined-in-container-spec/54398918#54398918) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398272/override-env-values-defined-in-container-spec).

Comment: And if multiple envFrom entries are specified that contain the same env var, the last one will take precedence.

> When a key exists in multiple sources, the value associated with the last source will take precedence. Values defined by an Env with a duplicate key will take precedence